# |replace filter is matching too many characters

Tags: filter, regex

I'm looking to format out image tags from a string using the `|replace` filter. The behavior I'm looking for is to give it a string like this:

`<img src="test.jpg"><p>some text</p><img src="test.jpg">`

and get back:

`<p>some text</p>`

Unfortunately, when I use `{{ snippet|replace('/<img(.*)>/', '') }}` it matches the entire string, from the opening `<img` to the second image's closing `>` rather than matching both `<img>` tags individually. How can I force the regex to match only through the first `>` it finds before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{{ snippet|replace('/<img([\w\W]+?)>/', '') }}
```

You can see an explanation of the regex in the right column of https://regex101.com/r/DvJHeY/1

Comment: Awesome, thanks again Brad!